# Output alternatives in Python

Tags: python

Is there any alternatives to the print statement for output in Python.
Also, how can I format my output text to be color-coded?

I'm a beginner programmer, pretty new to it.
Thanks

Comment: Colab and Jupiter note books, allow outputting to markdown. You could also output html, and pipe this into a html renderer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
sys.stdout.write()
```

Is one alternative. You can also write to `sys.stderr`. Personally, I use `sys.stdout` when I need to pass a generic "stream" to some function that will write to it. And open file is a stream, and `sys.stdout` is a stream. This way my function can be parametrized to write either to output or to file.

I also find `sys.stdout.write` more convenient than `print` for printing many things to a single line, as I find the ending comma syntax of `print` for suppressing the newline ugly and inconvenient.

Regarding printing to the terminal in colors, see this [other SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python).

Comment: I didn't know about the comma syntax for print. Thank you. I wonder if there is a way to also suppress the space python seems to replace the new line with.

Comment: @Musixauce3000 Which space is this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "display()" function instead of print() - I prefer this and it works well to display dataframes

```
display(dataframe)
```

or

You can also use Pretty printer : Sample code below

```
import pprint
stuff = ['spam', 'eggs', 'lumberjack', 'knights', 'ni']
stuff.insert(0, stuff[:])
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(stuff)
```

Comment: `NameError: name 'display' is not defined` From where did you import it?

Answer (score 0):

**IceCream — Never use print() to debug again**
You should try the package called **IceCream**
To install it, please use the following:

```
pip install icecream
```

For details on how to use it, please click [here](https://github.com/gruns/icecream)

An example:

```
from icecream import ic
a = 3
def duplicate(i):
    return i * 2

b = duplicate(ic(a))
```

ic| a: 6

```
ic(b)
```

ic| b: 6

Enjoy!

Answer (score -1):

You can use [PrettyPrint](http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html) for print data