# Return a board read from open file board_file. The board file will contain one row of the board per line

Tags: python

for a .txt looking like the below (already opened):

```
EFJAJCOWSS
SDGKSRFDFF
ASRJDUSKLK
HEANDNDJWA
ANSDNCNEOP
PMSNFHHEJE
JEPQLYNXDL
```

Return a board that will contain each row on a different line. Newlines are not included in the board.
I have the below code:

```
def read_board(board_file):
    file = open(board_file, 'r')
    line = file.readline()
    newList = ''
    while line != '':
        newList = newList + line.strip('\n') + '\n'
        line = file.readline()
    return newList
```

The result is : `'EFJAJCOWSS\nSDGKSRFDFF\nASRJDUSKLK\nHEANDNDJWA\nANSDNCNEOP\nPMSNFHHEJE\nJEPQLYNXDL\n'`

Any tips on how I can get this to list each row on a different line, as mentioned above? `+'\n'` doesn't do the trick...

Comment: Forgot to mention, cannot use print() !

Comment: What do you mean "cannot use print"? You get an error if you attempt to use it, or you are not allowed to use it?

Comment: i'm not allowed to use it

Comment: Yeah, that's likely to be a bigger challenge than how to get these onto individual lines. Can you use the Python `logging` module and log to stdout?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570269/output-alternatives-in-python may also be useful.

Comment: thanks  bouteillebleu, appreciate the input.

Answer (score 0):

file.readlines() gives list of lines

```
lst_lines = file.readlines()
```

lst_lines will be like: `['EFJAJCOWSS\n','SDGKSRFDFF\n'........]`

Now you can iterate over lst_lines list with for loop
line[0],line[1] is different line

```
for line in lst_lines:
  print(line)
```

Comment: i forgot to mention, i cannot use print. would have been much easier if i could